# How to call a function on widget closing in angular-dashboard-framework?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm using [angular-dashboard-framework](https://github.com/angular-dashboard-framework/angular-dashboard-framework) for a project and there I need to trigger a function when my widget is closed. So far I have found that adf broadcasts the message `adfWidgetRemovedFromColumn` when a widget is closed.
So I have created a event listener on my controller as followes

```
$scope.$on('adfWidgetRemovedFromColumn', function(event, args) {
    console.log('widget-removed');
    someService.someFunction();
});
```

The problem is that since the above message is broadcasted on rootScoop above listener get activated for every widget closed in the dashboard. How can I restrict this to only trigger when a certain widget is closed?

Comment: Does these widgets have unique id or something?

Answer (score 1):

You should add data while broadcasting the event like this-
`$rootScope.$broadcast('eventName', {'myWidget': $scope.isMyWidget})`

Here myWidget should be true only when click is on your desired widget. So, `$scope.isMywidget` should be true only when click is on your desired widget else false.

And then in listener you will execute code only if that paramter is true -

```
$scope.$on('adfWidgetRemovedFromColumn', function(event, args) {
    if (args.myWidget) {
        console.log('widget-removed');
        someService.someFunction();
    }
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Although this seems great I cannot change this since I am creating the widget on top of an existing framework and it's the framework which does the work of closing the widget.

I managed to resolve this by using listening to $destroy on my controller. Is that a good way of doing that?